# Plasma-Discover not starting on Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, discover-software-center

When I try to start Plasma Discover on my Kubuntu 20.04 by clicking on it nothing happens.

I can only start it on the command line with "sudo plasma-discover". Then it opens but the Discover start page with recommendations brings the error: "Application could not be loaded. Please check the Internet connection". But the Discover still works. Additionally: when I try on the command line only "plasma-discover" without sudo then I get this:

"Icon theme "gnome" not found".

I deinstalled and re-installed "plasma-discover" package, but it did not change the situation. Is there a way t reset the Discover again somehow?

Comment: I noticed, when I start it on the console with "sudo plasma-discover" it starts properly with some error messages on the console like this:
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
qrc:/qml/Feedback.qml:2:1: module "org.kde.userfeedback" is not installed
invalid kns backend! "/usr/share/knsrcfiles/ksysguard.knsrc" because: "Config group not found! Check your KNS3 installation."
adding empty sources model QStandardItemModel(0x55e5bb675680)
org.kde.plasma.libdiscover: Couldn't find a category for  "fwupd-backend"

Answer (score 0):

After further investigations I see that the problem only exists when I
use the taksbar of type "icons with running programms". When I use the
taskbar type "only icons" then Discover starts properly. It seems to be a bug in Plasma Discover in Kubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was:

```
sudo apt install plasma-desktop
```